# How to get the second word of an output from a command in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Hi I am trying to make a shell script.

```sh
sudo usermod -s $(whereis -b zsh) $(whoami)
```

`$(whereis -b zsh)` makes an error with `zsh: command not found zsh:`

The error seems to occur because the output of `whereis -b zsh` is `zsh: /usr/bin/zsh /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zsh /bin/zsh /etc/zsh /usr/share/zsh /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/zsh`

Now I would like to use `/usr/bin/zsh` for the script as an output. Is there any way to get the second word from the output of `whereis -b zsh`?

how should the script look like to get what I need?
shell script is quite difficult than I thought. Thank you everyone in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Better add quotes around commands expansion

```sh
sudo usermod -s "$(whereis zsh | cut -d ' ' -f2)" "$(whoami)"
```

Alternate method by getting `zsh` from the `$PATH`:

```sh
sudo usermod -s "$(command -v zsh)" "$(id -un)"
```

Comment: Quotes are unnecessary here. It's Zsh!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. As chepner already pointed out to me, this is **not** run by zsh, so you are right: The quotes are highly advisable. It's a good idea to use `command`.

Comment: This works!! And so does @user1934428 's suggestion as well. I'm not used to shell scripting yet... Still got long way to go. Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 1):

If you run it under bash:

Instead of parsing the output of whereis, use `type`:

```
sudo usermod -s "$(type -P zsh)" "$(whoami)"
```

Don't forget that `type -P` yields an empty string, if the program you are searching for is not in the PATH.

If it is not bash, you can also do a

```
sudo usermod -s "$(which zsh)" "$(whoami)"
```

Note that `which` issues an error message if the program can't be found, so if you need an empty output in this case you'll have to throw away stderr.

**UPDATE**: Thinking of it, IMO a better solution is the one suggested by Lea Gris: `command -v` is available on bash and POSIX shells, and yields empty output if the file can't be found.

Comment: `whence` is a `zsh` built-in; it's not clear (to me, anyway), that the script is being executed *with* `zsh`, only attempting to *locate* `zsh`.

Comment: @chepner: Fixed (I hope). Please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```sh
whereis -b zsh | awk '{print $2}'
```